# "Highest" string in strict lexicographic order

Tags: java

We have a set of strings in our program.  Given an arbitrary string, we want to find the "highest" string in the set (in lexicographic order) for which the given string is a prefix (if at all).

For example, assume that our set contains the following strings:

```
"This is a string_001"
"This is a string_002"
"This is a string_b"
"This is a string_A"
```

If the given string is `"This is a string"`, we should return `"This is a string_b"`.  On the other hand if the given string is `blah-blah-blah`, we should return null.

We have an implementation where we can find the "highest string", out of the longest candidate strings, but it is not the "highest" string in strict lexicographic order.  For example our implementation returns `"This is a string_002"` (over `"This is a string_001"`) but it does not return `"This is a string_b"`.

Comment: A big part of learning to program is gaining the skill to scan documentation for approaches to problems. If you scan docs for the class `String`, you'll find helpful stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your set is a `SortedSet<String>` of some kind (Like a `TreeSet<String>`, there's an elegant approach. First, use `SortedSet#tailSet` to get a new set of all elements of the set that are greater than or equal to the prefix string - which includes all elements with that prefix. Then just look at the initial elements of that set that have the prefix, and return the last of them.

```java
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Demo {
    // I prefer using an Optional instead of a null pointer to
    // indicate something wasn't found.
    static private Optional<String> findLargestPrefix(SortedSet<String> set,
                                                      String prefix) {
        // Get a set of all elements greater than or equal to the
        // prefix. Then, return the last element of that set that
        // starts with the prefix.
        String prev = null;
        for (String word : set.tailSet(prefix)) {
            if (!word.startsWith(prefix)) {
                break;
            }
            prev = word;
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(prev);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var set = new TreeSet<String>();
        set.add("This is a string_001");
        set.add("This is a string_002");
        set.add("This is a string_b");
        set.add("This is a string_A");

        System.out.println(findLargestPrefix(set, "This is a string")
                           .orElse("No match found!"));
        System.out.println(findLargestPrefix(set, "blah-blah-blah")
                           .orElse("No match found!"));

    }
}
```